# Apply textwrap.fill to every print on python script

Tags: python, printing

I would like to have my print output length limited to X characters.

I've been looking for some info and I found the command `textwrap.fill` which makes just what I was looking for by using something like:

```
print(textwrap.fill("Hello world", X))
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to apply this length limitation to every print without having to write it (I do have plenty of them) by creating or setting a class or something at the very beginning of the script.

Comment: Before looking at my somewhat complicated answer, would it be acceptable to just have a function `def pf(arg): print(textwrap.fill(arg, 70))`, and then everywhere you were calling `print` just call `pf` instead? It obviously won't give you the full API of `print`, and it won't affect anything that other modules you `import` try to output, and so on, but it has the virtue of being dead simple.

Comment: What do you want to happen when stuff gets printed that doesn't end in a newline? Eg, should `print('a', end=''); print('b', end=''); print('c')` print `abc` followed by a single newline, or should it print on 3 separate lines?

Answer (score 1):

Monkeypatching [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) *is* doable, but it's not a good idea. For one thing, what do you want to happen if someone does a `print(spam, eggs)`? Or `print(spam, end='')`? Or `print(spam, file=outfile)`?

---

A better solution is probably replacing [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) with a wrapper.

The normal `sys.stdout` is a plain old text file object, a [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) just like the ones you get from `open`, except that when you write to it, it goes to the console instead of to a file on disk.

And you're allowed to replace it with anything else that meets the [`TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) protocol.

And writing a `TextIOBase` is really simple. All you really need to implement is `write` and/or `read` and `readline` (depending on whether you're wrapping output, input, or both), and all our wrapper needs to do in `write` is to buffer up lines, `fill` them, and pass them to the real file object underneath.

Like this:

```
import io
import sys
import textwrap

class Filler(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, file, width=70):
        self.file = file
        self.textwrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=width)
        self.buf = ''
    def write(self, buf):
        self.buf += buf
        lines = self.buf.split('\n')
        self.buf = lines.pop()
        for line in lines:
            self.file.write(self.textwrapper.fill(line) + '\n')
    def close(self):
        if self.buf:
            self.file.write(self.textwrapper.fill(buf))
        self.buf = ''
        self.file.close()

sys.stdout = Filler(sys.stdout, 32)

print('Spam spam spam spammity ' * 10)
print('Spam', 'Eggs')
sys.stdout.textwrapper.width = 72
print('Spam ' + 'spam ' * 50, 'and eggs', sep='... ')
print('Spam', end=' ')
print('Eggs', end=' ')
print('Cheese')
```

---

Technically, I think I may be cheating in a few ways here:

- The docs say the ABC `TextIOBase` wants `detach`, `read`, and `readline`, even if they don't make sense here. But the ABC doesn't seem to enforce them as abstract methods, so I didn't bother.
- I *think* it's legal (and it works) to leave `encoding` and `errors` set to `None`, since we're just passing through to another `TextIOBase` and expecting it to do the encoding, but I can't find anything that *says* it's legal. And if some code were to test `sys.stdout.encoding` to see if it's UTF-8 or something, that might be trouble.
- Similarly for `newlines`. And, since I haven't tested on Windows, I can't be as sure that it works.

Also, forwarding other methods to `self.file` might be a good idea, like `fileno()` and `isatty()`. But I'd worry that any app that wants to access `stdout` as a TTY probably need to know about the `Filler` that we stuck in front of it, not just transparently go through it.

---

This is of course all Python 3-specific. In Python 2:

- [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) is a `file`, not a `TextIOWrapper`. The API you need to wrap is a bit different, and not nearly as well defined.
- Unless you `__future__` up the 3.x-style `print` function, `print` is a statement, so you can't monkeypatch it. (I mean, you could write an import hook that bytecode-hacks out every `PRINT_*` bytecode, or maybe even inject a .so that replaces `PyObject_Print`… but who cares anyway? It's Python 2.)

Comment: I _was_ going to post an answer, but it's so similar to yours that I won't bother. However, you should consider creating a `textwrap.TextWrapper` instance and call its `.fill` method. The `textwrap.fill` convenience function creates a new instance on every call.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, the disadvantage is that if you want to change the width, you have to either forward a `@property` in `Filler`, or explicitly set `stdout.textwrapper.width`, and now that I think about it, that's not much of a disadvantage.

Comment: Indeed. :) And the upside is that your Filler `__init__` could easily accept all the `Textwrap` kwargs and pass them on. Of course, the OP may not need that flexibility. Speaking of which, it would be nice to get some feedback from the OP...